# Resource route in Laravel with some methods

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I use only 'index' and 'show' methods from a resource controller. 
How to create a resource rout with some methods?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create resource route in Laravel without certain methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038981/create-resource-route-in-laravel-without-certain-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Route::resource()` by default enables all the routes to the respective Controller functions.

If you don't want to use all the functions, simply go for this method

```
Route::resource('name', 'Controller', ['only' => [
  'index', 'show'
]]);
```

Hope that helps :)